# Understanding reading realtime hardware streams (python)

Tags: python

I have question because I dont understand the principle behind it.

I wrote a python script that reads realtime data from a USB DVB-T Dongle in order to recieve data from a wireless temperature sensor. I am using a program called rtl_fm. This reads the data from the dongle and pipes it into my script. I wrote the script by searching for examples which were not too complicated.

In this script I use sys.stdin.fileno() to constantly read 512 bytes from the input stream. Now, what I dont undertand ist, why does this work? If the dongle, aka, the inputstream, would deliver data at a higher rate then the rate my script is reading, I would either loose data, or some buffer would eventually overflow. If the rate is slower, my script would at one point stop because there is no more data present.

Can somebody explain how/why this is working?

Thx.

Comment: How are you using `sys.stdin.fileno()` to read data? That function only returns the file descriptor, in this case, `0`. You should be using `sys.stdin.read(512)`.

Comment: I pipe it to the python script: rtl_fm parametery | python script.py -

Answer (score 0):

The OS's pipe handling is doing buffering for you. If you read too quickly your read will block. And if `rtl_fm` writes too quickly the write will block. Whether or not that loses data depends on how `rtl_fm` works.

BTW, assuming `rtl_fm` outputs raw bytes, in Python 3, you can read those bytes from `stdin` by reading from `sys.stdin.buffer`, rather than messing around with the file descriptor and `os` calls. (In Python 2, you can just read bytes from `sys.stdin`; at least, you can on Linux, and other Unix-like OSs that don't do newline translations on text streams).